# ionic 4 google-maps 5 beta "TypeError: Cannot read property 'BaseClass' of null"

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-native, ionic4

im trying to use ionic 4 google-maps@5.0.0-beta.20

i am following these slides: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zlkmoSY4AzDJc_P4IqWLnzct41IqHyzGkLeyhlAxMDE/edit#slide=id.g282d0a7bfd_0_140

I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'BaseClass' of null"

newlocation.page.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <h3>Ionic GoogleMaps Starter</h3>
  <div id="map_canvas">

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

newlocation.page.scss:

```
map_canvas {
  height: 90%;
}
```

newlocation.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-newlocation',
  templateUrl: './newlocation.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newlocation.page.scss'],
})
export class NewlocationPage implements OnInit {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(private platform: Platform) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.platform.ready();
    await this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
....
"@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.14",
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.0.0-beta.20"
....
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
        "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": (API-KEY),
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
```

Comment: Hey did you get any fixes for this issue.

Comment: nope I just used agm map plugin .. it looks kinda ugly and its documentation is bad but at least it worked on web and android (I didnt try it on iphone).... u can find questions about how to use it in stackoverflow.

Comment: hey Partha, good news, I was working on a new project and got it working. I had only to move the div outside the <ion-content> xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working,

I only deleted 'ion-content' and let 'div id="map_canvas"' alone

my info:

package.json:

```
. . .
"@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.22",
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "5.0.0-beta.22",
. . .
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="2.4.6">
    <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="(YOUR-API-KEY)" />
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="15.0.1" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
. . .
```

newlocation.page.html:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

newlocation.page.scss:

```
map_canvas {
  height: 90%;
}
```

newlocation.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-newlocation',
  templateUrl: './newlocation.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newlocation.page.scss'],
})
export class NewlocationPage implements OnInit {

  map: GoogleMap;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
  }
}
```

newlocation.module.ts

```
import { GoogleMaps } from '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx';
. . .
   @NgModule({
      providers: [GoogleMaps],
. . .
```

Note: for web you have to use 'ionic cordova run browser' not 'ionic serve'

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic V4, we need to define loadMap() method async call which will return promise.

```
async ngOnInit() {
  await this.platform.ready();
  await this.loadMap()
}
```

Comment: instead of adding in ngOnInit, can you please add in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: nothing changed.. aren't we supposed use the path '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx' for angular? why when i add '/ngx' it tells me GoogleMaps don't contain the method create?